# Oracle Inmemory_size

Tags: oracle

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какие-нить рекомендации по установке размера этого параметра? Какой-то минимум чтоли. Если на сервере 200гб ОЗУ, сколько безопасно можно отдать в inmemory_size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В документации сказано, что `INMEMORY_SIZE` устанавливает размер хранилища столбцов `IM` в памяти экземпляра базы данных.
По умолчанию значение равно 0 и хранилище столбцов `IM` не используется.
После установки этого параметра, база данных должна быть перезапущена, чтобы включить хранилище столбцов `IM`.
Минимальный размер, на который может быть установлен этот параметр, составляет 100 МБ.

Comment: Да, спасибо. А рекомендуемый размер например вычисляем? Или может ограничиваться возможностями сервера и желанием админа? :)

Comment: @ss_beer, размер колеблется в районе данных которыми вы будете манипулировать. Сколько вы считаете нужным, поставьте, будет мало, увеличите и распределите.